# Querying WAN IP lease time?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I know that one can go in `cmd` and can find his LAN IP lease time with `ipconfig /all`, but I want to know is there any way one can find WAN IP *lease time* knowing that the  ISP has given him a dynamic IP?

Comment: If it's for the purpose of trying to wait out the lease time to try get another IP address… most DHCP servers try to re-use the same IP on the same interface each time. My theoretically dynamic IP has remained the same for 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to check anywhere but on the device getting the lease.  In most cases this is the router.  Whether or not the router will show this information is a different issue.  I was curious if my router gave me the lease information, but after scouring through it, I couldn't find it.  You may have better luck with your router.